# How do I take an iPad screenshot that includes a picture of the iPad border around it?

Tags: ipad, screen-capture

I know how to take a normal screenshot with my iPad, but I'm looking to see how people on the internet are able to show content on the iPad in a picture that has the physical border of an iPad.

Do they just take a screenshot and superimpose the image?

Comment: Yes - it's just basic layering using two images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks, for mentioning my app, [AutoScreenshot 3D](http://itunes.apple.com/app/autoscreenshot-3d/id430515377?mt=8)!

I created it for myself, as well as other developers, who want to superimpose their screenshot onto an actual image of an iOS device, and have it displayed at an angle, with mirror effect.  Makes a nice screenshot for iTunes or web or print!

The PRO version, for $0.99, lets you provide your own background image.  By default, it ships with an iPhone 4.  You can also download images that you can use for free, from http://www.AutoScreenshot.com.  We will add iPad images in the future, but you can google for an acceptable one.

A free version is awaiting Apple's approval and it only uses the default background.

Comment: Very nifty and cool little app!!

Answer (score 4):

A lot of the times those screenshots are taken on a computer from the iPhone or iPad simulator on the developer's Mac. It's included in the SDK if you have that it's free to download just not the development version of the iOS 5 SDK. Other than that take one of those images or an image of an iPad off the internet and then photoshop your screenshot into it and it should look pretty good.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a free browser app for adding a frame around the screenshot: [FrameApp](http://www.appdemostore.com/frameapp). 
It works like this: you upload your screenshot, select the desired frame (iPad, iPhone, Kindle Fire, Google Galaxy - horizontal or vertical) and size, and then save your png. The best part is that the png has rounded corners, so that you can use it with any background. The tool is HTML5-based, so it works only in the browsers which support this (Firefox, Chrome & Opera).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this collection to use your screenshot in. I think this is what you may be looking for. They also make one for the iPhone.

http://www.teehanlax.com/downloads/ipad-gui-psd/

Comment: Note that the above is for mockups only. So, you're not allowed to use it in ads, on a website, etc. It's for planning out an app, not enhancing screenshots of an existing one. Not sure why they made that rule, but it is the case.

Answer (score 1):

There's an app for that...
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/autoscreenshot-3d/id430515377?mt=8

Unfortunately, I can't see if it provides an ipad as well as the iphone border.

Answer (score 1):

Using AirServer on your Mac , It's possible to screenshot the iPad with your requirement.

Comment: The answer should explain how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use Reflector to Airplay the iOS device onto your computer screen
2. Press shift-command-4 to enter "screen grab mode"
3. Hover over the mirrored device and press the space bar (this select only that window)
4. Click mouse for screen grab (to desktop)

The screen grab will be the mirrored iOS screen AND any device screen you've chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a specific **app** to (1) take a regular screenshot, then (2) superimpose the image to give it a border, this isn't possible out of the box.

I've had the iPad for a while now, and was wondering the same thing. But alas, GIMP makes borders for me.

Answer (score 0):

Apple developers (which is where most of these screenshots come from) are given access to various marketing gumpf from Apple including device  images (with empty screens) that they can just overlay their screenshots in, as well as things like "App Store" logos, etc.

I can't remember the exact wording (nor can I be bothered to re-read it right now) but I think it's against the Developer agreement to give those images out as they are. They're for marketing and that's their only licensed purpose.

If you want them (legally), pay Steve $99/year and he'll furnish you with the goods.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Box shot king](http://www.boxshotking.com/) which allows you to easily do the iPad and many other items - it even allows you to create book covers. Incredibly simple to use but comes at a price ($99 a year).

Comment: $99 a year? There are a bunch of low-cost solutions in the App Store to compete with. Makes you wonder how long they will stay around.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Reflector](http://reflectorapp.com/) you can broadcast the iPhone and iPad screens to a Mac. Reflector superimposes a black (or white) border on the screen image.

The coolest part about Reflector is that with a screen video capture app, like [SnapzProX](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/snapzprox/), you can record the iPad in action.

We plan to use Reflector for our iPads at school on our Mac & PC desktop classroom machines.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free app, [DS Screenshot](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/ds-screenshot/id808138012?mt=8&uo=4&at=10lqRJ&ct=SE), that will add your screenshots to all device images at the same time. It does both iPhone and iPad.